# SQL Developer - Add new connection is greyed out

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

suddenly, my SQL Developer turned off, i can't add any connection to connect to my work remote databases, i tried to factory reset the views, uninstalled and reinstalled the app. still can't figure out how to fix it !

[image: Hi, suddenly, my SQL Developer turned off, i can't add any connection to connect to my work remote databases, i tried to factory reset the views, uninstalled and reinstalled the app. still can't figure out how to fix it !]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, i needed to configure the JDK under AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\21.4.1\product.conf

"SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301"

Answer (score 0):

Your connections.json file has probably been corrupted.

You can find that file and try to repair it yourself, OR you can rename it to something else, and when SQLDev starts up, it'll give you a default connection panel, but no connections in it, you'll start from scratch.

Older copies of sqldev will have a connections.xml.

Comment: Thank you, but still the same situation, I replaced the file from a working machine, nothing changed :/

Comment: Did I ask you to replace the file? I asked you to rename/delete the file. If that doesn't work, try renaming the entire system21.4.3... directory.

Comment: In order to "repair the file", as you mentioned, I renamed it, tried to fix it, deleted it, but still the same issue, I tried to replace it, same.

Comment: then you need to take more drastic measures, rename the entire system21.4.3 directory, like i suggested on the 12th.